# Set background color of TabView - SwiftUI 2.0

Tags: swift, swiftui

Trying to use my custom color in my tabview.

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56969309/change-tabbed-view-bar-color-swiftui) now, but they only said the option for system colors, and I have created a custom color called `"Bg"`, how can I call it? This is what they suggested:

```
init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```

When I try to replace `UIColor.blue` for `Color("Bg")` I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(Color("bg")) 
}
```

Comment: How can I do it without the extension? I think creating an extension for 1 color is not a good idea. Also the naming is just an example, not my real color name :)

Comment: It works but the background looks faded, I'll take a screenshot

Comment: Look, it looks horrible lol https://i.postimg.cc/7Z7P89PZ/IMG-CD2247658-FA3-1.png. It's like the yellow goes above the text and icons instead of going into the background

Comment: Now it displays correct, by the it seems I don't need the extension, only with `UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(Color("Bg"))` in the init did the trick

Comment: Wops, there is a flag when I used the multitask to switch to another app and came back the color disappeared, it seems the color in the init won't work :/

Comment: Maybe it was a bug, or it could be that I added: `UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false` which you could add to your answer